# link to direct to page with iframe with auto login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on my site and I'm using a 3rd party service to host some user contests in. But I do not want users to be redirected to another website, with different URL in browser, so I decided to use an iframe.

The 3rd Party site gives each of its users a unique direct login url, I have set each user up and account and have control over the direct links for them.

I have this working, but I hate using a form method, when you refresh the page with iframe, it give you a popup message to consent to resubmitting the form data.

I have a member page setup that will only show each user his personal direct login link. When clicked it opens up another page on my site, which has the 3rd party website in iframe, and it auto logs them in.

Does anyone know a better method to achieve the same thing I've done here

Loaded on iFrame content page

```
<?php /* Template Name: IFrame */ ?>
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['myTargetSite'])) $myTargetSite = "";
else $myTargetSite = $_POST['myTargetSite'];
if($myTargetSite=="") {
    die("Page Missing");
} else {
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"
                            prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<body>
<iframe src="<?php echo $myTargetSite; ?>" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;height:100%;
                  position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
<?php   
}
?>
```

Loaded on member account page

```
<script>
function goToSite(thisLeagueURL) {
    document.myLeagueSelect.myTargetSite.value = thisLeagueURL;
    document.myLeagueSelect.submit();
}
</script>
<form name="myLeagueSelect" action="http://my-site.com/mycontests/myleagues/" 
      target="_blank" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="myTargetSite"/>
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="goToSite(
 'http://newsite.com/login/uniqueusername;PASSWORD=402bbd5c85af3590b50ced27340c1002'
    )">LOGIN</button>
```

Comment: You are at the mercy of how the other site works unless they have an api you can work with to put content on your site

Comment: understood , but looking for another method instead of using form to post action

Comment: There isn't one since it is a post unless they have an ajax api